# urlManager-route overriding gii's route. How to compensate?

Tags: yii

This feels like a really silly problem, but here goes:

I have a route like this

```
'rules'=>array(
    // domain.com/slug/23452/sometitle
    '<slug:\w+>/<kiji:\d+>/<title>' =>'Like/Add',
),
```

It works great and does everything it needs to, BUT it overrides the default gii-route:
`http://domain.com/gii/default/login`. And I'm not really sure how to fix it other than commenting out my custom route every time I want to use Gii. Can I somehow decare the gii-routes before my other routes to make it prioritize the Gii-routes?

Answer (score 0):

I found out from `yii/framework/gii/GiiModule.php` that you can use those routes:

```
'gii'=>'gii',
'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Please note however that Gii should only be enabled on your dev server :-)